# toggle - Jquery I want to whenever click on first button it show and then click on second button then instead first button's div tag hide

Tags: javascript, toggle, show-hide

> See Here i create my css file for show paragraph

```
          <div><a href="#about" class="toggle">About</a></div>
          <div><a href="#photos" class="toggle">Photos</a></div>
          <div><a href="#rates" class="toggle">Rates and Reviews</a></div>
        </div>
        <!-- middel -->
        <div class="col-lg-6" align="center" style="background-color:#CFF">
          <div id="about" >about </div>
          <div id="photos" >photos</div>
          <div id="rates" >Rates and Reviews</div>
        </div>
```

> see here, describe jquery code. please help in implements

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

$('.toggle').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).toggleClass('hidden show');
});
```

});

Answer (score 2):

[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function is what you need to show or hide specific element.

[.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) only add or remove specific class but it will not work for adding `hidden` and `show` class at same time

Replace `$(target).toggleClass('hidden show');` with `$(target).toggle();`

```js
$(function () {

$('.toggle').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#mainDiv').find('a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#detailsDiv").children().hide(); 
    $(target).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv"><div><a href="#about" class="toggle">About</a></div>
          <div><a href="#photos" class="toggle">Photos</a></div>
          <div><a href="#rates" class="toggle">Rates and Reviews</a></div>
        </div>
        <!-- middel -->
        <div class="col-lg-6" id="detailsDiv" align="center" style="background-color:#CFF">
          <div id="about" >about </div>
          <div id="photos" style="display: none;">photos</div>
          <div id="rates" style="display: none;">Rates and Reviews</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks for help, but i want to when load page default show 'About' then click on 'Photos' show photos and hide about.. then i click on 'Rates and Reviews' hide Photos.. ;)

Comment: and one more help from you brother. How to add active class.

Comment: What do you mean by `active` and where you want to add? Be specific and it's better to ask a new question if you stuck at somewhere and also don't forget to set answer as accepted

Comment: it mean whenever click on Rates and reviews then it colored.. and when color on photos. do . same

Comment: Using above example and jQuery's addClass would do what I expect you want:  
$(this).addClass('active'); Remember to remove class from children like: $("#detailsDiv").children().removeClass('active');

Comment: See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Farving/s45sb7on/2/ as I made some mistakes above :)

Comment: well, all is fine.. but one more help.. whenever i applied to on text color not work just blinking.    css -  .

.active{
  color: red
}

Comment: Yupp, i want to change text color whenever select, not change Background. :)

Comment: Updated answer and replace `red` with whatever color you want to use in `active` css class

Comment: I cannot say anything without showing your code that why it's not working...Check snippet code and try to follow it in your code...

Comment: Dear Brother @SarjanDesai , how implement defualt active whenever open page.? i want default active color set on about.